# How to convert string to list in python. Like "['a']' to ['a']

Tags: python, arrays, django, string, list

I have a list from a database in the form of a string, and I want to convert this string to a list.
For example if I get `'["a","b"]'`, I want to convert it into this: `["a","b"]`.

**I've tried `list()` method.**

```
userf = user.pending
print(userf)
#userf is "['animation']"
userf.append(tosend).save()
```

Comment: Is the list actually stored as Python syntax in the database, or could it be JSON instead? It's impossible to tell because your example is valid in both.

Comment: The list stored as python syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `literal_eval`

```py
import ast

l = '["a","b"]'

ast.literal_eval(l)
```

output

```
['a', 'b']
```